# Using if statements in actions

Tags: github-actions

I have this main.yml workflow right here:

```
name: Testing

on: 
  push:
    branches:
    - main
jobs:
  upgrade-kubectl:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Install kubectl version
        uses: ./.github/actions/promote-image
        with:
          kubectl: 'latest'
```

and my action.yml metadata file:

```
name: "Helm, Kubectl or Devspace installation setup"
description: "Install a specific version of Helm, Kubectl or Devspace. Acceptable values are latest or version strings like 1.15.0"
inputs:
  kubectl:
    description: "Version of Kubectl"
    required: false
  helm:
    description: "Version of Helm"
    required: false
  devspace:
    description: "Version of Devspace"
    required: false
runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - name: Setting up kubectl
      uses: azure/setup-kubectl@v1
      with:
        version: ${{ inputs.kubectl }}
    - name: Setting up Helm
      uses: azure/setup-helm@v1
      with:
        version: ${{ inputs.helm }}
    - name: Setting up Devspace
      uses: loft-sh/setup-devspace@main
      with:
        version: ${{ inputs.devspace }}
```

Currently I am just supplying the kubectl version in my workflow, but when the action is triggered it is running all 3 steps instead.

How do I make it so that if I supply one version it only runs the one step, supply two version it runs two steps respectively, etc.

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you can't use `if` condition in composite actions, you would have to do the check (and even maybe the setup) another way through a script execution eventually.

Comment: if conditions are now supported for composite actions. Took a bit of researching but I have solved my question. Thanks though !

Comment: Great! I wasn't aware of that. I added an answer with a solution that could help people with the same issue in the future. Let me know if you did it that way as well.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that now [conditions are supported on composite actions](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-11-09-github-actions-conditional-execution-of-steps-in-actions/).

Therefore, you could add if conditions at each step level according to the input used.

In that case, your `action.yml` workflow file would look like this:

```
name: "Helm, Kubectl or Devspace installation setup"
description: "Install a specific version of Helm, Kubectl or Devspace. Acceptable values are latest or version strings like 1.15.0"
inputs:
  kubectl:
    description: "Version of Kubectl"
    required: false
  helm:
    description: "Version of Helm"
    required: false
  devspace:
    description: "Version of Devspace"
    required: false
runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - name: Setting up kubectl
      if: ${{ inputs.kubectl != '' }}
      uses: azure/setup-kubectl@v1
      with:
        version: ${{ inputs.kubectl }}
    - name: Setting up Helm
      if: ${{ inputs.helm != '' }}
      uses: azure/setup-helm@v1
      with:
        version: ${{ inputs.helm }}
    - name: Setting up Devspace
      if: ${{ inputs.devspace != '' }}
      uses: loft-sh/setup-devspace@main
      with:
        version: ${{ inputs.devspace }}
```

Note that the syntax:

- `if: ${{ inputs.kubectl != '' }}` works
- `if: ${{ inputs.kubectl }} != ''` doesn't

Comment: Yup thats basically what I did too, cheers !